# Restore nuget packages defined in .nuget folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

There are some nuget packages (e.g. `OpenCover` or `ReportGenerator`) installed without changing packages.config in any of the project, but there is a `[Solution Dir]\.nuget\packages.config` created with the package reference information.

When VS builds the solution, the packages defined in that file are not downloaded at all (even I have auto restore nuget enabled).

How can I restore them automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSBuild based package restore, that uses **NuGet.targets**, which is enabled in Visual Studio by selecting **Enable NuGet Package Restore**, does not seem to support restoring solution level packages, which are those that are defined in the **[SolutionDir]\.nuget\packages.config** file.

Looking at the NuGet.targets file on build it restores the packages for the project using the project's packages.config file but does not use the solution's packages.config file.

So your options are:

1. Stop using the MSBuild based package restore. Visual Studio, with recent versions of NuGet, will automatically restore all packages, including all solution level packages, when you build.
2. Run **NuGet.exe restore YourSolution.sln** from the command line, or PowerShell console, or as a pre-build step, to restore all packages. NuGet.exe can be used to restore all packages on a build server if you are using one.

The MSBuild based package restore has been deprecated by the NuGet team so I would use option 1) if this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The reason I want to restore solution level package is because it is something not controlled by me, for example `OpenCover` and `ReportGenerator` will only add reference information to `[SolutionDir]\.nuget\packages.config`. So I will probably use option 2 to give it a try.

Comment: You could also modify the NuGet.targets file to restore the solution level packages. This is similar to doing a pre-build step but more work. It would also cause solution level packages to restore for every project compilation which is a bit inefficient.